# Can Healpy compute a bispectrum to study non-gaussianity of the CMB map?

Tags: python, healpy

Hell everyone,

Can Healpy compute a bispectrum of the CMB map?
It looks like there is no such built-in function in Healpy library.

Thanks!

All the best,

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no support for computing a bispectrum, if anyone implements it, it would be nice to have a pull request contribution towards `healpy`.